# Update datetime value to 0 milliseconds, nanoseconds and microseconds .000

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I am looking to update all datetime values in a table to end in .000.

Here is an example of some of the ones causing errors:

```
2022-06-06 11:55:23.317 
2022-06-02 13:38:22.293 
2022-06-02 16:17:51.343 
2022-06-10 10:37:31.420
```

Any row where the last three digits are not 000 need to be set to 000 like below:

```
2022-06-06 11:55:23.000 
2022-06-02 13:38:22.000
2022-06-02 16:17:51.000 
2022-06-10 10:37:31.000
```

Comment: Why not just use a `datetime2(0)`? Then the value is only accurate to 1 second.

Comment: `causing errors` -> maybe fix that instead of updating all of your data to work around it? Or just have whatever application is outsmarted by milliseconds query a view instead of the table, where you can convert to `datetime2(0)` as Larnu suggests? Also do you just want truncation, or do you want to round up when the value is >= 500? e.g. `2022-06-06 11:55:23.667` -> `2022-06-06 11:55:23.000` or `2022-06-06 11:55:24.000`? Your sample data should include at least one edge case like that.

Answer (score 1):

As Larnu mentioned in comment you can try with:

```
UPDATE people SET timestamp=CAST(CAST(timestamp AS DATETIME2(0)) AS DATETIME)
```

Comment: I, personally, don't see the need to `CAST` back to a `datetime` here. Also, this does look a bit confusing, as `timestamp` (in SQL Server) in a (deprecated) synonym for `rowversion`, which has *nothing* to do with dates and times; hopefully the OP's column *isn't* called `timestamp`.

Comment: Thank you this was very helpful and the cast back to datetime was needed to keep the trailing 000.

Comment: @AnimalMind What is the data type of the column? If it's `datetime` you won't need the cast to do anything (the data isn't _stored_ the way it's presented). If it's not `datetime`, you should fix it.